# Carregar include PHP apartir de um ID Externo

Tags: php, html, include

Galera, boa noite!

Tenho o seguinte Código:

```
        <!-- Box do Cupom -->
        <article class="box_cupom">
            <?php include("cupom.php"); ?>
        </article>
```

Esse include PHP carrega uma página externa que trás algumas informações de um "Cupom Não Fiscal". Eu gostaria que essa página fosse carregada apartir de um ID de uma Div de dentro do include. Exelmpo:

```
        <!-- Box do Cupom -->
        <article class="box_cupom">
            <?php include("cupom.php#ID"); ?>
        </article>
```

Porém, quando escrevo dessa forma o PHP me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Warning: include(cupom.php#initialstart): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

Exite alguma forma de fazer isso em PHP para que não precise usar Frames do HTML?

Comment: Qual é o código de cupom.php?

Comment: O include não vai funcionar assim pois ele busca pelo nome do arquivo e, como não existe um arquivo chamado cupom.php#algumIdQualquer, nunca vai carregar. Entendi que você quer injetar o conteúdo de cupom.php na página em questão, mas qual é a ideia do uso do ID? Poderia deixar mais claro?

Comment: Você quer que após o include a página seja direcionada para uma div especifica ? Está um pouco confuso

Comment: @elvex O include, no php, aceita querystring?

Comment: Até onde sei, não. Tu deve passar o nome do arquivo correto mesmo. Mas como o @PedroAugusto disse: está um pouco confuso, qual é o seu objetivo?

Comment: Caro Jefferson, include não entende HTML, e também não entende querystrings, INCLUDE é parte do PHP, que é uma linguagem processada no back-end e pode devolver qualquer coisa, html, txt, jpeg, depende do que vc deseja enviar como "resposta HTTP". O include serve para juntar 2 arquivos e processa-los como se fossem um unico script PHP, claro que tem variações de comportamento, tipo o include suportar `return`, mas para resumir, include só inclui um HTML em outro em seu script, porque o output do incluindo foi escrito como HTML.

Answer (score -1):

o arquivo do include seria uma especie de CUPOM FISCAL, porém eu não queria que pegasse o cabeçalho pois é grande (height), eu queria que o arquivo do include sempre carregasse após uma DIV com tal ID, mostrando assim a "lista das compras" e deixando o cabeçalho mais acima.

A Class CSS "boxcupom" tem width de 300px e height de 450px; e overflow scroll.

Então conforme o Cupom tem mais item, ele vai aumentando... Mas é como falei lá encima, não queria que pegasse o Cabeçalho....

HELP

Comment: Faça o include "completo", oculte o que você não quer com css

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia fazer utilizando o método GET, por exemplo se quiser pegar pelo ID 22 você pode utilizar esta solução.

```
    <!-- Box do Cupom -->
    <article class="box_cupom">
        <?php include("cupom.php?id=22"); ?>
    </article>
```

e no cupom php você pode pegar o id por:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET["id"];
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi por que negativou a questão, quando é assim diga o que você espera e por que não é uma solução válida.

Da maneira que você quer incluir nunca vai funcionar mesmo, por que o include pega o nome do  arquivo, para passar uma informação para este arquivo é necessário ou mandar um método get ou de alguma forma passar a informação para a página que você quer chamar.